# How to explain a fast-acting "tar pit" projectile weapon?

Tags: weapons, low-fantasy

In movies or on TV usually for entertainment reasons, quicksand is quite often and inaccurately portrayed as a kind of super fast acting, almost inescapable and extremely deadly trap capable of swallowing entire humans and animals whole.

So in my world there's this weird grenade-sized projectile that essentially does this very same thing. Upon activating it causes the ground underneath its victims feet and within a certain radius to turn into a strange sticky tar-pit like substance (basically fast acting quicksand but much harder to get out of, which is why I've decided on making it sticky substance instead)

This causes victims to rapidly sink inside the ground until the chemical reaction or strange phenomenon eventually ceases, re-solidifying the ground underneath. Which either leaves the victims trapped or in the worst case scenario encased/swallowed whole into the ground.

I've was already planning on handwaving this with magic but I ask this question more-so out of curiosity that anything.

[image]

Comment: Made on Gallifrey.  But, serious comment: How would you judge the answers?

Comment: Acid resistant humans. But not acid resistant surface.

Comment: Does it have to work on *any* terrain or is it OK to work on a limited range of natural surfaces? (presumably you can have the planet/battlegrounds frequently occur on that type of ground)

Comment: @VLAZ The terrain/planet/battleground  thing was my initial idea but I decided to go with a projectile weapon option instead, which feels much weirder and more fun, in my opinion anyway. So I would like for it to be applicable on all type of surfaces alike. Also I don't really mind just handwaving all of it as magic, just wanted to see if there was some kind of semi-plausible way of going about this.

Comment: @MichaelKutz I was planning on handwaving all of it as magic anyway so it's no big deal, I just asked this question to know if there was some kind of semi-plausible way of going about it. A simple grenade-like projectile that causes the ground to momentarily turn into  a quicksand/tar-pit substance.

Comment: Have you ever seen the videos of people stomping/jumping on the beach on dry sand? Suddenly it turns semi-liquid and moves, after enough agitation (though not enough for people to sink into it really)?

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate electrostatic cohesion between molecules with a field effect? I can't think of one, but if there was, I see some potential. Alternatively, some means to break interactions between atoms in molecules. Again, not sure how you could without more energy than is worth discussing. Across the board, a big bomb is simpler, easier, cheaper, etc.

Comment: @DWKraus Interesting ! Hope I'm not being of a pain but could you elaborate a little on the subject. Let's just say energy isn't a problem since I'm pretty much dealing with magic here anyway, how would this work exactly ?

Comment: I was hoping for something better than handwavium, but if you disrupted the cohesion of matter, solids would start behaving like liquids, and liquids like gasses. It's not quite disintegration, but similar. Matter forms bonds usually because they are energetically favorable, so I can't quite see the mechanism. It would probably need energy input, get cold, then heat as the bonds reestablished themselves (messily). I may be picturing it a little off. A person would sink into an icy puddle, then cook in a mass of altered matter. Anyone care to comment? I'm open to input.

Comment: @DWKraus Thanks for clearing that up ! On the handwavium thing, I think your answer and @ Slarty 's one (below) might very well be the closest we can ever come to explaining such a strange contraption.

Comment: Or it might work the exact opposite - all the energy stored in the bonds would create a big exothermic reaction, and BOOM. Imagine frozen salt water rendered into a mass of hydrogen, oxygen, chlorine and metallic sodium. Depends on how the handwavium worked. The first version assumes as close to net zero energy as possible, and would rapidly reverse. The second is more plausible but needs more input, and doesn't match your question as well.

Answer (score 3):

It’s highly unlikely that something the size of a grenade would contain enough material to effect a large enough area.

What might work but would need to be much larger would be some large underground air pump that could turn the surface (sand, mud or dust?) into a fluid bed of low density. Anyone standing on it falls right through (proper fictional quick sand style) as they are denser than the fluidized bed around them. And when it’s switched off they would become trapped there.

A similar mechanism of gas in water has sunk ships and oil rigs.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Have it release a liquid that soaks into the soil and reduces its density to below 1010 kg/m^3 (the average density of the human body). It compresses the liquid via extreme pressure, or if you wanna go there, warping space so it's bigger on the inside. If we work with a soil of an average density of 2650 kg/m^3, and using gasoline, or a liquid with a similar density, that liquid has a density of 700 kg/m^3. If we go with an equal volume of gasoline and soil, the density should be 1675 kg/m^3, which is too dense. But if we were to go with 3 parts gasoline for every part soil, we have a density of 1188 kg/m^3. 7 parts gasoline, 1 part soil, and the density is 944 kg/m^3.

And as a bonus, the slurry is also flammable.

Comment: Liquids generally fill in the vacant pores that already exist in soil, so wetting soil typically makes it *more* dense, not less. For density to decrease, you'd need to actively move some of the soil elsewhere, and replace it with a lower-density fluid. Dumping liquid on the ground doesn't displace anything but air, you're basically putting *more* weight into the same volume.

Comment: Nuclear Hoagie, what if it's a special liquid that absorbs into the ground, and expands to reduce its density until the mixture is lighter than water?

Comment: I suppose that would work, but the expanding material would need to *displace* soil - you could add low-density material, but it would have to push high-density material out of the way to have the intended effect. This will take a *lot* of energy - imagine being buried in dirt up to your neck, and trying to push dirt either out or up to dig yourself out. The energy needed to move the dirt would be like a hand grenade in the first place, rather eliminating the need for the more creative aspects of the weapon.